# Load one react application as a component of another react application to avoid page reload and prevent state loss

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactive-programming, flux, reactjs-flux

My project is a journey of three react applications, User finish steps from application 1 then redirected to application 2 and then redirected to application 3.

When user press back button and lands in previous application, since page reloads while navigating from one application to another, state of previous application is lost and user see first page of application than last page of previous application.

I tried to call another react application as a component of separate react application by rendering generated js in component will mount.

When application loads it renders another application inside it but page gets stuck in some infinite loop resulting in page kill.

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: You could store the app state in local storage if they hit the back button, and then rehydrate the store when the app gets reloaded.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet but Code splitting may be one solution.